# FFMPEG Creating 1 FPS video with background audio and -shortest flag generating unexpected output duration

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -loop -1 -i image.jpg -i audio.wav -shortest out.mp4
```

Using ffmpeg version 2022-02-24-git-8ef03c2ff1-full_build-www.gyan.dev

Here is the ffprobe for audio.wav

> Input #0, wav, from 'audio.wav':   Duration: 00:00:20.21, bitrate:
> 1411 kb/s   Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001),
> 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s

and out.mp4 (note that the duration is 1:20, instead of the 20 second duration of the audio file).

> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':   Metadata:
> major_brand     : isom
> minor_version   : 512
> compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
> encoder         : Lavf59.17.102   Duration: 00:01:20.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 156 kb/s   Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj444p(pc,
> bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1200x1443 [SAR 1:1 DAR
> 400:481], 120 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbr, 16384 tbn (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : VideoHandler
> vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]   Stream #0:10x2: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 139 kb/s
> (default)
> Metadata:
> handler_name    : SoundHandler
> vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

Comment: This is [a known bug circa 2012](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5456) and Gyan posted [a suggested workaround on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/keobv8/shortest_doesnt_work_as_intended/)

Comment: @kesh Ok thank you.  I really appreciate the link.  

Also, I wish I was using linux rather than a windows build, but WSL 2 was causing lag on my PC when using some other memory intensive programs so I uninstalled it :\  Is it more common to run into ffmpeg bugs using gyan's windows builds?

Comment: Tbh, I do not know as I primarily use FFmpeg to do rudimentary stuff myself (read/write media data for research use), but I highly doubt differences in builds aren't all that much (I'd venture to say even across OSes) other than the dependencies.

Comment: Makes sense.  I am kind of surprised that this bug has persisted for so long.  I believe ffmpeg is one of the most active open-source communities.  But atleast there seems to be a workaround, as you shared.

Comment: @kesh I just tried adding the arguments from the link to my command, and it did help, but not fix the issue entirely.  It outputted a 25 second video instead of a 1m20s video.  But again, the output should be 20 seconds long (as that is the duration of the input audio).

I will post this on the reddit link as well, but perhaps you may know how this can be corrected.

Also, I added a -t 20 flag to limit the output.  This works, but it is not dynamic if I need to perform this command on a new audio clip. :-(

Comment: Just thought of an idea. What if you set `-framerate 60` for the input then use low framerate output `-r 1`? Does this help?

Comment: @kesh I tried your recommendation, in unison with the workaround from the reddit link.  Unfortunately, encoding became horribly slow after adding your suggestion, like so: ffmpeg -framerate 60 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.wav -shortest -fflags shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -r 1 -y out.mp4

Comment: How about 2 pass approach? `ffmpeg -framerate 60 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.wav -shortest -fflags shortest -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -y out.mp4` followed by `ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -shortest -fflags shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M -r 1 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a copy -y out1.mp4`? I tried a dummy case and it still lengthen a bit but maybe manageable?

Comment: With Python (or other scripting language) you can use `ffprobe` to get the exact duration of the audio and set up the `ffmpeg` call dynamically. Is this something you're comfortable with?

Comment: @kesh Yeah, I have been contemplating using Python instead of command line, makes sense that it would add some benefits such as this.  But wish it could be done by just using the ffmpeg executable.  Will try the 2 pass as well, busy attempting to build a version of ffmpeg that supports nVidia CUDA for hardware acceleration, seems useful for encoding speed..